Implementing Continuous Averaging Memory for White Noise Signal in Simulink
I'm currently working on a project where I need to develop a continuous averaging memory to compute the average frequency spectrum of a white noise signal. The goal is to achieve a Degree of Freedom (DOF) of 120, meaning that the resulting spectrum should be based on the averaging of 120 data packets. This system needs to be continuously updated, integrating new data while discarding the oldest, thereby maintaining a constant number of averaged data points.
What I Need:
I’m seeking advice and suggestions from the community on the best approach to implement this in Simulink. Specifically, I need guidance on:
Optimal Simulink Blocks: Which Simulink blocks or combination of blocks would be best suited for this task?
Configuration Tips: Any specific settings or configurations that might be critical for this implementation.
Example Models: If anyone has example models or has worked on similar problems, sharing those would be incredibly helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
I have explored many various methods and Simulink blocks, but I haven’t been able to fully achieve my goal. Here’s a brief overview of what I’ve attempted:
Sliding Window Average: I used the Buffer block to create a sliding window of 120 samples, followed by the Mean block to compute the average. This setup didn’t quite work as expected for continuously updating the average frequency spectrum.
MATLAB Function Block: I implemented a custom MATLAB Function to manually compute the moving average. While this provided some control, it didn’t integrate seamlessly with Simulink’s real-time processing capabilities.
Discrete FIR Filter: I considered using a Discrete FIR Filter configured for a moving average, but I’m not entirely sure how to adapt this for frequency spectrum analysis over a fixed number of data packets.
